# Generic Collections - Ensuring Collections Contain Only One Type of Object?

Tags: .net, generics, oop

Let me start with the definitions of the objects with which I am working and then I'll do my best to explain what I'm after:

```
class CacheItem<T> where T : EntityBase

class CacheCollection : List<CacheItem<EntityBase>>
```

OK, so my generic collection, CacheCollection should be a list of CacheItems which I can manipulate according to various business rules.  One thing I'd like to ensure, howerver, is that each CacheCollection I instanciate only works for a single type of EntityBase.  For instance, I have two classes inheriting from EntityBase; Case and Client.  I'd like each CacheCollection to handle only one of those types and not mix them.

What changes can/should I make to accomodate this design requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always make CacheCollection a generic type itself and then pass that up the inheritance tree to CacheItem:

```
class CacheCollection<T> : List<CacheItem<T>> where T : EntityBase
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get rid of `CacheCollection` (which serves no purpose) and have e.g.

```
List<CacheCollection<Case>> cases;
List<CacheCollection<Client>> clients;
```

no?

Comment: CacheCollection has a number of method within it that deal with how many items are held in cache, which items get "bumped" when the number is exceed, etc.  Would there be a better place to put this type of logic?

Comment: In that case, I like @Justin Niessner's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make CacheCollection generic, so you explicitly state the type that it can contain:

```
class CacheCollection<T> : List<CacheItem<T>> where T : EntityBase {}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
class CacheCollection<T> : List<CacheItem<T>> where T:EntityBase
```